# pylance autoimports aren't working as they should

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I started a project in python using visual studio code but noticed something with autoimports

I have a function in a file (hellofolder/hello.py) with the following code

```
def hello():
    return "hello!"
```

However, when i try to import this function from another file(doHello.py) It doesn't appear as an import option [image with the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUkf3.png)

But when I use quickfix to import the function
[quickfix image recognizing the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYh1u.png)

even after deleting the import statement, it still becomes available without having to use quickfix again [image of what I would expect usually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtz1U.png)

I don't know if this is how it's supposed to work or not, but I would like advice on how to get it to be like the third image

[relevant settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAmLP.png)

[the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7KOJ.png)

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I submitted it to [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19822). I can wait for the follow-up explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3324) on github.

At present, Pylance does not provide relevant functions. Only when the package is used will the prompt of automatic completion appear.

Vscode is a lightweight editor. This is done to prevent users from customizing too many packages, resulting in too long reading time.